# Inserting data using subqueries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using the following query to insert data in MS access from another table but getting an error

```
INSERT INTO PROJECT ([PROJECT].[Target date],[PROJECT].[percent]) VALUES 

SELECT [PROJECT PROGRESS].[MD Target date], [PROJECT PROGRESS].[MD % of completion]
FROM [PROJECT PROGRESS];
```

Comment: (sigh)  What's the error message say?

Answer (score 3):

I don't use Access very often, but don't you need to get rid of the VALUEs keyword? Ie, it should be

```
INSERT INTO PROJECT ([PROJECT].[Target date],[PROJECT].[percent]) 

SELECT [PROJECT PROGRESS].[MD Target date], [PROJECT PROGRESS].[MD % of completion]
FROM [PROJECT PROGRESS];
```

Or it could be

```
INSERT INTO PROJECT ([PROJECT].[Target date],[PROJECT].[percent]) 
VALUES("test",11)
```

You're combining the syntax for two different operations